# JQuery hover issue on tabbed elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, hover

First post here, excuse my naivety but I'm fairly new to JQuery coding.

Utilising someone else's code, I have created a page with a tabbed navbar (#tabsection) which uses JQuery to show/hide the relevant text sections (#textsection) underneath. It works by toggling a class .hidden on and off dependant on which is active. This is my JS:

```
(function($){
$('#tabsection .x-container').on('hover', '.menu-item', function(){
   var textshow = $(this).index('#tabsection .menu-item');
   $('#textsection .x-container').addClass('hidden');
   $('#textsection .x-container').eq(textshow).removeClass('hidden');
});
})(jQuery);
```

This works fine when hovering between each tab, but when you've the mouse away from the nav, the last visible section stays visible without fading out.

Is there a simple addition to my code which would enable me to add the class .hidden to all #textsection elements when the mouse isn't hovering over the tabbed section anymore?

Comment: Hi Paul, please add your html/css code to make it easier to help. Creating a working fiddle would be even more helpfull.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/hover/ - please read the manual, you will see there is a callback function for when the mouseleaves too

Comment: `on('hover'...` is a shortcut for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, so you should add two callbacks to hover, the first is what happen when mouseenter and the other when mouseleave. read the documentation above

Answer (score 0):

you can use hover by passing two functions

1st for mouse enter and 2nd mouse leave.

```
$('elem').hover(function(){// mouse enter}, function(){// mouse leave})
```

something like this

```
$('#tabsection .x-container .menu-item').hover(
  function() {
   var textshow = $(this).index('#tabsection .menu-item');
   $('#textsection .x-container').addClass('hidden');
   $('#textsection .x-container').eq(textshow).removeClass('hidden');
  }, function() {
   var texthide = $(this).index('#tabsection .menu-item');
   $('#textsection .x-container').removeClass('hidden');
   $('#textsection .x-container').eq(texthide).addClass('hidden');
  }
);
```

note: you may need to fix selectors, not sure how your html looks.